# Переобразование даты с unix в обычную в форме Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Доброго времени суток.
Дело в том, что в проекте для сохранения даты я использую unix-time. Сгенерировал CRUD. Удобнее всего будет отображение и добавление данных, естественно, не в unix-time, а в обычном формате dd.mm.yy.

Если вывод в GridView можно настроить атрибутом date, а переобразование dd.mm.yy в unix-time сделать в `beforeSave()` модели, так с выводом данных в само поле проблематично.

Объясню на живом примере. При клике "Update" мы получаем данные в форме, причем данные чистые, без переобразования unix-time в dd.mm.yy:
[image: пример даты]

А нужно отображение даты по указанном формате. Как вариант вижу: после объявления экземпляра класса модели переобразовать данные с unix-time в dd.mm.yy и передавать их на форму. Но, думаю, это не самый верный вариант.

Comment: а как в коде прописано? там же вроде можно указать имя колонки и параметры его представления...типа такого `'Until',
                        [
                            'attribute' => 'Until',
                            'format' => ['date', 'php:dd.mm.yy']
                        ],`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, данные с контроллера идут на view, который в свою очередь рендерит _form.php. Выглядит инпат, на данный момент, так: `<?= $form->field($model, 'until')->textInput() ?>`

Comment: А... тебе для input.... таки может использовать форматтер? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-formatting.html и если везде используется Unix, тогда вообще можно его в конфиге настроить форматтер https://stackoverflow.com/a/34331845/6104996

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше в самой модели объявить дополнительную переменную:

```
class MyModel extends Activerecord
{
    public $untilDate; // Новая переменная для даты

    public functions rules()
    {
        return [
            ....
            ['untilDate', 'date', 'format' => 'dd.MM.yyyy'], // Правило валидации
        ];
    }

    // Присваиваем дату в эту переменную после возвращений данных из БД после поиска
    public function afterFind()
    {
        $this->untilDate => Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($this->until);
        parent::afterFind();
    }

    ...
}
```

В `view` выводить эту `untilDate`. Ну и как вы писали уже в `beforeSave()` сохранять в `until` дату в unix методом `strtotime()`.